# SwiftUI two TextField of different type causing lags

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am building a login View, as simple as having only an email `TextField` and a password `SecureField` next to each other:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

However, the result shows some strange UI behavior:

[image: Lag image]

When I switch between two text fields, the UI lags with an unexpected jump.

I have done some experiments, and figured out that:

1. When two `TextField` have same `textContentType`, UI does not lag:

```swift
// good

TextField("Email", text: $email)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

TextField("Password", text: $password)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
```

2. When two `TextField` have different `textContentType`, UI lag:

```swift
// bad

TextField("Email", text: $email)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    .textContentType(.emailAddress) // <-- notice here

TextField("Password", text: $password)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    .textContentType(.password)  // <-- notice here
```

2a. In particular, a `TextField` and a `SecureField` cause lags:

```swift
// bad

TextField("Email", text: $email)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

SecureField("Password", text: $password)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
```

I believe the reason is that **when attempting to focus a `TextField` with different type, the keyboard dismisses and shows back again**, which causes the lag.

I am using XCode 12.4, running on iOS 14.4.

Could anyone help me to resolve this annoying issue? Many thanks!

Comment: is this on a device ?

Comment: The keyboard does not change though they have different content types. I do not have it. Are you suure you are not doing something else?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yes, on my iPhone 12 pro max.

Comment: @mahan I am pretty sure. I just start a new Xcode project, copy-paste above code, and then install on my iPhone 12 pro max, the behavior appears.

Comment: @mahan what is your device, iOS version and xcode version? BTW, you have to switch focusing for several times, since the UI lags randomly.

Comment: The same as you. I always run the latest version.